# AWS Log insights - Query

Tags: aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Need to filter JSON inside the from AWS log insights

we are adding custom JSON while logging from .NET so we can filter

below is my sample and i want filter  @Message - MessageTemplate where timestamp > x or user is equal to some value

```
@ingestionTime  
1694665437360
@log    
144457421649:/aws/elasticbeanstalk/test
@logStream  
2023/09/13T14.25.15 - f547c4da-8a22-4322-a30f-ea5f5696491c
@message    
{"Timestamp":"2023-09-14T04:23:56.7147192+00:00","Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"{\"user\":1234,\"Method\":\"Post\",\"Action\":\"Drawing\",\"Status\":\"Success\",\"Message\":\"Get Drawing Called\",\"Source\":\"test\",\"TimeElapsed\":\"\"}","Properties":{"SourceContext":"test.Services.Services.DrawingService","ActionId":"b4947847-c337-49ae-a684-231611dd4fb2","ActionName":"test.API.Controllers.DrawingController.Drawing (test.API)","RequestId":"0HMTKCU117A37:00000002","RequestPath":"/api/drawing","ConnectionId":"0HMTKCU117A37","ApplicationName":"Serilog.WebApplication"}}
@timestamp  
1694665436714
Level   
Information
MessageTemplate 
{"user":1234,"Method":"Post","Action":"Drawing","Status":"Success","Message":"Get Drawing Called","Source":"Main","TimeElapsed":"15"}
Properties.ActionId 
b4947847-c337-49ae-a684-231611dd4fb2
Properties.ActionName   
API.Controllers.Drawing
Properties.ApplicationName  
Serilog.WebApplication
Properties.ConnectionId 
0HMTKCU117A37
Properties.RequestId    
0HMTKCU117A37:00000002
Properties.RequestPath  
/api/drawing
Properties.SourceContext    
BWS.test.Services.Services.DrawingService
Timestamp   
2023-09-14T04:23:56.7147192+00:00
```

some thing like this filter

fields @timestamp, MessageTemplate

| filter MessageTemplate like /"Status":"Success"/

am looking for a way if i want check timestamp greather etc how do i achieve it in a better way